# Code seem do play as the order as I want

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self pingSplash];
    UIViewController *next = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
}
```

I mean to finish pinSplash then pushViewController, but it directly goto ViewController page, even without finishing pingSplash, what is a good way to do that kind of job?

For the pingSplash part:

```
- (void) pingSplash
{
    SKSplashIcon *pingSplashIcon = [[SKSplashIcon alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ping.png"] animationType:SKIconAnimationTypePing];
    _splashView = [[SKSplashView alloc] initWithSplashIcon:pingSplashIcon backgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor] animationType:SKSplashAnimationTypeBounce];
    _splashView.animationDuration = 5.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:_splashView];
    [_splashView startAnimation];
}
```

Comment: Update your question with details about the `pingSplash` method.

Comment: So what's the problem? You don't want to push the view controller until the 5 seconds animation is complete?

Comment: Yes, I just want to wait for 5 seconds then push the view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pingSplash` method returns as soon as it starts the animation which is why you end up pushing the view controller too soon.

There are a few ways to solve this. One way would be to pass a block to the `pingSplash` method that is run after an appropriate delay.

Here's one way:

Update the `pingSplash` method to take a completion handler block that is run after the 5 second delay.

```
- (void) pingSplash:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    SKSplashIcon *pingSplashIcon = [[SKSplashIcon alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ping.png"] animationType:SKIconAnimationTypePing];
    _splashView = [[SKSplashView alloc] initWithSplashIcon:pingSplashIcon backgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor] animationType:SKSplashAnimationTypeBounce];
    _splashView.animationDuration = 5.0f;
    [self.view addSubview:_splashView];
    [_splashView startAnimation];
    if (completion) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(_splashView.animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completion();
        });
    }
}
```

Then update your `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self pingSplash:^{
        UIViewController *next = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
    }];
}
```